# COUNTIFS when criteria has more than 255 characters

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I was looking for a formula in Excel that will search into different ranges parts of text that meet another criteria. So, basicalLy it is a COUNTIFS. While trying to use the formula, which perfectly does work, I am facing a problem when searching for strings which include more than 255 characters.

Here is an example of the formula I am using (COUNTIFS in english).

```
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO(Sheet!$D$2:$D$10;"First criteria";Sheet!$H$2:$H$1000;"second criteria")
```

As the first string has more than 255 characters, always the result is 0 elements found.

Has somebody faces this issue previously? Any idea on how to solve it would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `COUNTIFS`,

But your criteria will need to move to Cells. In my example I have used `A1` and `B1`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet!$D$2:$D$1000=A1)+0,(Sheet!$H$2:$H$1000=B1)+0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I ma researching  alittle bit and it seems taht you are right! But it still outputs an error saying that instead of the comma I need *. By doing this I get many more items counted than there are.

Comment: you may need to use semi colon rather than a comma. but I have tested this and will count as expected

Comment: Right! But semicolon is what what worked perfectedly for me! It may be because of different versions of Excel probably. Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

You can also use an array in your criteria field, then wrap the countifs() with an sum. (without the sum the countifs will only count the first member of the array):

[image]